# Loop Splitting Performance Issue

Tags: c++, performance, loops

I implemented the gaussian-elimination procedure over GF(2). I used a two-dimensional 64-Bit Integer-Array to store the Matrix in row-major representation (rows of the matrix are stored in contiguous array). I implemented the gaussian elimination on the rows of the matrix in the following manner:

[image]

where (A)^i denotes the i-th row of A. I then realized that if i splitt the loop at lines 5-6 as follows i get slightly better performance:

[image]

I would expect to get slightly worse performance, cause I'm iterating the whole outer loop again... does anyone have an explanation for that behaviour? Is the compiler doing some tricky optimization stuff, that's easier to perform on the splitted variant? (compiled with g++ -O3)

(If pseudocode doesn't lead to the answer, i can provide a minimal example of code)

Comment: What's your test suite (matrices, their sizes)? What's their internal representation, row or column major?

Comment: matrices for test cases are between 64<= n <= 1000 and as mentioned i'm using row major represtantion

Comment: A minimal example of code would indeed be helpful.

Comment: Is it possible that your performance is limited by the speed of moving the matrix from main memory to cache? Even with N=1000 it might still fit in cache.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason to expect worse performance from your second solution - both algorithms are in [image: O(n^3)], they even have same constant: in first solution your outer loop is in [image: O(n^3)], in second one you have two loops in [image: O(\frac{n^3}{2})].

In practice, your second solution might have better CPU caching characteristics or be more suited for compiler optimization. In particular, since you're operations are over GF(2) / Z(2), they can be expressed as binary operations over words - which would result in large speedup. Depending on your implementation (and constraints on *n*), algorithm may be optimized to [image: O(n^2)] in the end. We can't really tell without taking a peek at your code, though :).